# r how to remove trendlines from model diagnostic plot ()

Tags: r, plot

I am running a simple linear regression model

```
lm.SR <- lm(sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi, data = LifeCycleSavings)
```

This is my diagnostic plot using the default plot() function

```
 plot(lm.SR)
```

I like to remove the **red trend** line from the diagnostic plots. Not sure how to do that. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
plot(lm.SR, add.smooth = FALSE)
```

When you plot an object of class `lm` you are using `plot.lm`, so you can use `?plot.lm` to see the available options.